# Java generic type argument in consumer interface

Tags: java, syntax, compiler-errors, generic-programming

In the main method in the below class there is the usage of the below method: input.

However this will result in a compilation error as in the usage below, the field amount which is wrapped inside the consumer is instance of an Object and not a generic type that can be molded into an int.

Therefore to resolve the compile error we would need to cast (int) to amount then using ok((int)amount);

```
public class Constructor {

public static void main(String.... args) {
    input("reason", (amount) -> {
        int amount2 = amount; //also error as amount is Object and not int
        ok(amount); //error as amount is Object and not int
    });
}

public static void ok(int i){ //paramter i MUST BE INTEGER

}

public static <T> void input(String reason, Consumer<T> answer){

}
}
```

I want to be able to freely use the amount value in the consumer as an int/string/list

Heres an example of how I want to free utilize the amount field:

```
usage:
ok(attribute("key"); //this will work and is freely moldable into int/string/whatever

code:
public <T> T attribute(String key){ //This will return whatever you want it to, and is how I want the amount field to do inside the consumer
    return aHashMap.get(key);
}
```

Comment: Java is a statically typed language, and each variable has only one type. You cannot use the same variable freely as "int/string/list". Also, the type inference mechanism is limited - it will not see that you are using the argument later to call a method with an `int` argument; that has no impact on the type it infers. If the generic type is not restricted at the point where you use it, the compiler will infer `Object` and be done with it.

Comment: Considering the second code block in the op which shows that generic type can be utilised in some more dynamic and less static writing, is there no way that java can recognise amount as a generic type that can be an int rather than just an Object?

Comment: @kay The second code block doesn't compile, does it?

Comment: @Sweeper it does

Comment: First, you are missing a closing `)` in the first line. Second, whatever type of `HashMap` `aHashMap` is, it probably is not `HashMap<String, T>`  because `T` can change with each method call to `attribute`. You probably need an unchecked cast there.

Comment: Its <String, Object>

Answer (score 0):

The proximal issue here is that the Java compiler has no basis on which to infer the type parameter `T` of method `input()`.  You can solve that by using any of several ways of expressing it explicitly.  For example,

```
 <Integer>input("reason", (amount) -> {
    int amount2 = amount; //also error as amount is Object and not int
    ok(amount); //error as amount is Object and not int
 });
```

or

```
Consumer<Integer> intConsumer = (amount) -> {
    int amount2 = amount; //also error as amount is Object and not int
    ok(amount); //error as amount is Object and not int
};

input("reason", intConsumer);
```

On the other hand, it's not clear what value you gain from using a generic method there.  An alternative would be to declare it differently:

```
public static void input(String reason, Consumer<Integer> answer){
    // ...
}
```

If you don't want `input()` to specify the `Consumer`'s type parameter, then maybe instead you want

```
public static void input(String reason, Consumer<?> answer){
    // ...
}
```

, though that in itself does not help Java infer the `Consumer`'s type parameter where that method is invoked.

> I want to be able to freely use the amount value in the consumer as an int/string/list

That doesn't make sense as stated.  The existence of a local variable `amount` in the `Consumer`'s implementation is a detail of that implementation.  An implementation that uses the argument in any way that is not general to all `Object`s is therefore limited to use with a subset of types.  Since `String`, `List`, and `Integer` have no common superclass more specific than `Object`, no such consumer could handle all three types.  You could have a *different* `Consumer` implementation for each of those types, but then there is no meaningful sense of **the** amount common to those consumers.